# Error while updating and installing a package in ubuntu server 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, updates, apache2

I am new in the world of linux . I am trying to update and install some packages in Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS but it is showing error . I have seen lot on same question in this site but not able to solve the problem that why asking it .

Error while Updating:

```
$ sudo apt-get update  
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease    
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease    
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease    
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Error while installing a package

```
$ apt-get install apache2  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
```

Comment: You have an underlying network issue - either the connection itself or name resolution (DNS) is not working

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you ping something out of your local network?

Answer (score 0):

Please, run the following command in a terminal. 
nslookup. Then, see if your server DNS could be resolved running

> server

If the server DNS resolution is correct then you have another problem.
Exit nslookup

Or, maybe another problem.

Clean your cache:

```
sudo apt-cache gencache
man apt-cache
```

gencaches creates APT's package cache. This is done implicitly by all commands needing this cache if it is missing or outdated.

Comment: Problem still exist